Will I die or get a decent shock using an inverter?
I want to know if I can get shocked if I have the following setup?
From my understanding, because the inverter (let's say a small 300W) is considered a "standalone" AC source and not connected to the grid, I therefore should not get shocked or die if I touch the live or neutral. This is due to my body not completing the circuit, hence no current can flow through me.
Hence it will not be very wise to connect my inverter to the earth's ground and also bond my neutral and earth, since this would now complete the circuit if I come into contact with the earth's ground.
Is this correct?
EDIT 2:
The inverter is a Meanwell Modified Sine Wave. The Earth cable is connected to the metal enclosure of the inverter. The Neutral is not bonded to the Live or Neutral

EDIT 3




You are missing a couple of things. First of all, we don't know the innards of your specific inverter. It might internally bond the PE and N terminals. Or then N and L are both live compared to PE. And your desktop PC metal case will connect the metal case to PE, and every peripheral (keyboard, headset) will be referenced to the PE. So do not assume anything. You might get a shock no matter if you touch live or neutral, if you are referenced to PE. You also don't give any context, is this inverter in your home, in a car, or bolted to same metal chassis than some other equipment.

@Justme thank you for asking those points. Please see edit 2

@Justme I have also updated the drawing to show the earth connection as per your comment

@Justme so if I do not bond the neutral to ground then I will be safe, because if live does touch the load's casing then the inverter will essentially blow up if the ground is bonded to the neutral.

There are still unknowns. Is the PE terminal of the mains socket connected to the inverter chassis? Or is the PE on mains socket floating, completely disconnected, or does it have filter caps to GND? Because if you have a metal cased PC, and the PE terminal is left floating, the PC metal case has half mains supply on it, due to PC having filter caps from L and N to PE.

@Justme the PE cable is connected to the main socket and goes straight to the inverter's chassis. By chassis I mean the enclosure. There is no filter caps. See EDIT 3

@Justme sorry I spent a few hours trying to get this inverter opened

@JoeyB A better question is WHY do you want to compromise the earth ground? 99.9% of the time you wouldn't want to do what you are intending. You are likely going to create downstream problems including safety. Your EMI will likely be worse. Also, the inverter might use that connection for ground faults. So, again, what is your concern that you want to disable an intended safety connection?

@MOSFET the green/yellow is NOT returning to the source. I have checked the green/yellow cable is only connected to the enclosure of the inverter. The green/yellow cable does not connect to the DC+, DC-, AC live or AC neutral.

@JoeyB That seems unlikely - that green/yellow wire is almost certainly connected via Y caps. Because if what you're saying is true, why would the manufacture install a dead wire at all?

@MOSFET the green/yellow is screwed on the DC side of the enclosure and there is no connection under the PCB  or ontop linking the chassis to any Y CAP, I think I just purchased a fire hazard....

Manufacturer says isolation between input and output is 100Mohms/500VDC. The mains output is thus floating, not referenced to 12V input or chassis. The mains output PE is tied to chassis. The chassis has no instructions how to install/tie/bond it, and there is no separate chassis terminal.

Think about it for a minute... If you grabbed the live or the neutral wire you would get a mild electric shock but the only return current path is the few pFs of capacitance from you to the inverter that would carry the current. This still could be dangerous, so you need a chassis (for the load and inverter) to protect the user.
If you shorted live or neutral to the ground of the inverter it should fault for multiple reasons, many inverters have an overcurrent protection against faults and also fault protection. If the ground is connected into the inverter  on the inside of the unit and you had a fault then the voltage on the outside of the chassis (of the load) would be near zero.
What you show is live being connected to ground of the inverter, which is the same situation and should not be dangerous as long as the inverters ground is tied internally.

You need to ohm out the chassis to see if it connetct to the ground of the inverter. The inverter will likely have more than one ground.

The chassis is not connected to the DC ground nor the AC "ground" nor is the chassis connected to the live or neutral.

Then the chassis is not safe, there is no return path.

By not safe you mean the chassis can also "sit" at 230V? Since the PE is connected directly to the Chassis

No, it means there is no current return path back to the unit, so there is no way to generate a faulting current. Any faulting voltage on the load will light it up to 230V which means you could get a current pathway through a human or anything else touching the device. Does your device have certifications like UL?

E13/EAC and CE approvals

Should I therefore connect the green/yellow cable to the blue (Neutral) cable?

You need an ETL mark or it is unsafe, no this is not a good idea as it could create problems.

I hope you are not the actor. But in this case, as drawn, the actor is still alive. There are 2 fault conditions: a. no PE connected to the housing and b. voltage on the housing. The probability of an accumulation of faults is small. It becomes life-threatening if the actor touches something that is earthed.

Can I ask why it is not a good idea to connect the blue cable with the green/yellow cable?

Because the unit is not designed to do so and there is no schematic to verify if it is safe.

Sorry Voltage Spike, silly question. Thank you for your help.

@arnisz that does not make sense, the inverter is a standalone unit and not connected to the earth's ground. There is no return path, unless you seeing a returning part that I am not, kindly post a drawing of what you mean.

@JoeyB Also, if there is no isolating transformer, it could be very dangerous for a user.

@VoltageSpike there is a transformer, however I am not going to try anything with a device that is made not to be safe in the first place.

@JoeyB I assume the inverter is in a vehicle. In this case, PE is the chassis of the vehicle. To fulfill the tripping condition of the line protection, PE and neutral must be connected in the inverter. This means that in the fault case shown, the "LIVE" touches the metal housing, a short circuit occurs and this triggers the fuse, so there is no danger. But I don't see any fuse or line protection shown and that's the problem!

Noted, however, if you are making an assumption in a comment, kindly include those assumptions. As you can see your assumption was not correct and can lead to a new can of worms. The inverter says it has overload and I think short circuit protection, however no details on how fast these protection mechanisms engage are shown, so I will take this with a pinch of salt
